# Mathematical Physics references in the spirit of Segal's lectures

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory

There are a few lectures about topological quantum field theory of Graeme Segal on youtube. The first one is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAd8NYMLhQc&list=PLBRuQw6qo-a86TLd4dNU-quP50emHLkTJ&index=15).

I am really interested in the mathematical descriptions of classical mechanics, special relativity, quantum theory,... that he gives in this first lecture.

I do not understand everything he says here. For example, I don't see why he says that an "ontology is a functor", and I don't know what is a $*$-algebra.

Do you know of a book summarizing these mathematical physics topics and explaining what Segal is doing here, written at the level of a mathematics bachelor or a physics graduate student? (It can assume knowledge of Lie groups, topology, some category theory,... but still be explicit - for example explaining why "ontology is a functor")